# Add items to CLion's New Project window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, clion, intellij-plugin

I need to add an item to the list of new CLion projects. It's a plugin written in Java with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2

I found [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000055950-how-can-you-add-items-to-CLion-s-New-Project-window)  and followed what he said by adding a "directoryProjectGenerator" in the plugin.xml

I created the class

```java
public class testClionGenerator implements DirectoryProjectGenerator {

    @Override
    public @NotNull String getName() {
        return "Test CLion Project";
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable Icon getLogo() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void generateProject(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull VirtualFile baseDir, @NotNull Object settings, @NotNull Module module) {

    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull ValidationResult validate(@NotNull String baseDirPath) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I don't know what else to do. How do you change the panel on the right when you do "new project"? What function is called when you click on next/cancel/create?
Do you have any tutorials?

This is the first time I've used StackOverflow, so I apologise if it's not very well done ^^'.

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.